# What might cause Entity Framework to throw an exception with message "(some type) is neither a super-type nor a sub-type of (some other type)"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm dealing with an EF problem I'm finding very difficult to debug...previously, there was a table-per-type inheritance setup governing the different user types in my system - one root type common to all users, and several different subtypes based roughly on the type of person using that account. Now, I have run into issues requiring me to remove the inheritance and instead place a UserId property on each subclass which is a foreign key to a User's Id property. So now instead of being a User, other user types will have a User navigation property.

I've removed all the inheritance associations using the EDMX designer, I've added all the UserId properties and their associations, made sure all the other user types now have their own Entity Keys, and gotten the association and navigation property for the User set up on each specific. However, when I actually run my application, I receive a TargetInvocationException with the message telling me that "User is neither a super-type nor a sub-type of (other type)".

I've been looking for other references to this error message for a little bit now and can't find anything, and I'm unable to determine what's causing it. There appear to be no more references to any sort of inheritance between User and the other types in my EDMX, but still the message persists. No one I know has ever seen it before.

There really isn't any code I can provide for reference; it seems to be a mapping issue. Has anyone seen an exception with this particular message before?

Comment: What line of code does the error occur on?

Comment: Top three lines of the stack trace:
at System.Data.Common.EntitySql.SemanticAnalyzer.<CreateBuiltInExprConverter>b__74(BuiltInExpr bltInExpr, SemanticResolver sr)...
at System.Data.Common.EntitySql.SemanticAnalyzer.ConvertBuiltIn(Node astExpr, SemanticResolver sr)...
  
   at System.Data.Common.EntitySql.SemanticAnalyzer.Convert(Node astExpr, SemanticResolver sr)...
  
No line number available, evidently. It happens the first time I attempt to retrieve an entity of any type.

Comment: It seems like there's something in the EDMX indicating that your entity is inherited. Did you generate your EDMX from the database?  If so, try generating a new EDMX from the updated database, then compare the EDMX files.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was not actually inside the EDMX as I had suspected. Usually when there is a problem with the mapping, the code will always blow up on the same line, at the point where I attempt to reflectively instantiate a repository of entities. Since this was where the exception was thrown, I thought it was a mapping issue, but turning custom errors off for the project showed that inside the constructor for a specific repository, another developer had inserted a call to `ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<User>().OfType<(user sub-category type)>()`. This is what was causing the problem. I suspect that the exception did not show me this line while debugging because the repository's constructor was called reflectively. After changing this call, everything works.